# How would I create a machine learning based text parser?

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining

I have many documents that have the same sections, but have different formatting. How could I make a model to segment the document into given sections?

I have tried making classifiers for specific sections (one classifier to determine the opening of a section and another classifier to determine when that section closes).

In a given document, perhaps I make a classifier to determine the formatting between sections and effectively use that as a delimiter.

What do you think of these approaches? Is there a better way to do something like this?

Comment: Since it wouldn't be helpful to repeat information that you already know, it would be useful if you outlined what you already know about document segmentation. What methods did you learn about when you did your literature review for document segmentation? Which papers are you drawing on? How are these papers similar or dissimilar to your problem? Please note that "What do you think?" is not a great way to frame a question, because it's just an invitation to free-form comments; more information about how to use this site is in the [help].